# How to git pull with two users?

Tags: git

I deploy my applications by cloning repository into production server.
When I make some changes I just go to the production server and invoke : git pull . 
I don't know if this is the right way of deploying but it works fine for me for now.

But I have one issue, recently I've started working with another developer and to
update the repository we have to know each other passwords and do git pull on production server, which is of course nonsense . Before GIT I used SVN and there was no such issues, 
everybody could invoke svn update with his account.

How to solve this issue or what is recommended way of deploying application from git ?

Comment: You could use a central server (like GitHub) and use separate `ssh` keys...

Comment: yea thx, I think i will go for ssh keys

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that you don't have the right permissions to run `git pull` on a repository checked out by another user, you can try to initialise your production repository using `--shared=all`, which will tell git to set permissions so that anyone can run git commands.