# How two users can make git pull in same local git path?

Tags: git

I have two robot users on my Linux system. Both of them should do `git pull` to update scripts before launching them. Is it possible to make both of them to work with the same local version of git?

In  other words, both

```
robotA@work-station:/git-project git pull 
robotB@work-station:/git-project git pull
```

should work

Comment: It is same problem as here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27837257/how-to-git-pull-with-two-users

Comment: Have you tried it and encountered problems? Or are you just wondering?

Comment: I tried and encountered with subj

Answer (score 1):

You could pull to a shared drive and then both could work from the codebase there.

However, I don't see why each of them can't just clone the repository onto their local drives themselves...

Comment: Unfortunatly this way do not work.
I tryed chmod 777 on all /git-progect* directory initialy owned by robotA.
After pull by robotB new files in   /git-progect/.git are not owned by robotA and he cann't do git pull without sudo